# Is there a way to ignore certain character in Deserialization?

Tags: c#, deserialization, webapi

I am trying to Deserialize an object from APIRequest with System.Runtime.Serialization. My problem here is that I have this field

```
[DataMember]
public long? Odometer { get; set; }
```

and in my API I receive sometimes some wrong format. Ex: 204.101

Is there a way that I can ignore the "." character ? (The value 204.101 it is equal to 204101)

Comment: What serializer?

Comment: Using Newtonsoft.Json? You could make a custom formatter. But honestly can you not fix this issue at the source? I.e. prevent the thousend seperator from being included in the json

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json is the serializer that I use. I cannot fix this at the source because I don't have access to the source.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to hook into the deserialization process; the easiest way probably consists in decorating your *Odometer* property with a `JsonConverter` attribute, pointing to a custom converter which takes care of the custom handling logic.

```cs
[DataMember]
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
public long? Odometer { get; set; }
```

In a naive yet simple approach, the custom converter may simply get a textual representation of the parsed value and parse it again after removing the offending dots, like:

```cs
class MyConverter : JsonConverter<long?>
{
    public override long? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, long? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", reader.Value);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return Int64.Parse(value.Replace(".", String.Empty));
    }
    
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, long? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // TODO

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

An alternative, possibly better approach may require defining a custom type to hold your *Odometer* value and writing a custom `JsonReader` for that type: but it could end up being overkill for your usage scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [string.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0) method and [CultreInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-5.0) to specify wether it's using a dot or a comma.
check out the [Double.toString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-5.0) doc for more . 
basically take the value 204.101 and convert it to string as so:

```
double value = 204.101;
string specifier;
CultureInfo culture;

specifier = "G";
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("eu-ES");
string ParsedValue = value.ToString(specifier, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
ParsedValue = ParsedValue.Replace(".","");
value = Double.Parse(ParsedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like and upvoted Efran's answer, but I've hacked something similar...which is essentially using a custom formatter w/o having a separate custom formatter type.

```
[DataMember(Name="Odometer")]
private string odometerRaw;
public long? Odometer
{
  get
  { 
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(odometerRaw) ? 
      null: 
      long.Parse(odometerRaw.Replace(".","")); 
  }
  set
  { 
    odometerRaw = value.HasValue ? 
      value.ToString(): 
      null;
  }
}
```

This is naïve in the extreme, and good for a one-off, but you might want to write some extension methods - or a full blown converter type somewhere to do a more robust parse if this is a recurring problem in other places. You've been passed a string with a legit format for locales that use '.' as a separator character. This does not make a legal json *integer*, but it does make a legal json *number*, which is why it got as far as your code.